# Two Tooltips Show Up HTML/CSS

Tags: html, tooltip

```
    <style type="text/css"> span:hover { } span[title]:hover:after { color: yellow;  } </style> <span title ="this is text"> Testing </span>
```

In the browser I am using (Google Chrome), the code above displays two tooltips, one that looks like expanded text, and one that seems to be generated by the browser. How do I fix this so that there is only one tooltip showing when I scroll over the word "Testing"? I want to keep the yellow one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the appearance of the tooltip since its **browser-dependent**.

However if you want to style your tooltips, you can use JS libraries like [JS Toolip](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/javascript-tooltip).